# Density chart of S&P500

Tags: self-study, skewness, kurtosis

I am examining the daily log returns of the S&P500 Index and I have negative skewness and excess kurtosis. However when I chart the density plot I am seeing positive skewness - does this seem wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is not necessarily wrong:** The visual appearance of positive skewness here is because of the slight positive skew of the "bulk" of the distribution.   However, just as with the kurtosis statistic, the skewness puts high weight on values that are far from the mean (since it is cubing the distance from the mean) and so it may be turned negative if there is a fat tail on the negative side.  From the graph you can see some fatness in the tail at around the $-2.5$ mark, which would have a negative effect on the coefficient of skewness.  So essentially the "bulk" of your distribution has slight positive skew but the negative tails might be fatter than the positive tails, leading to an overall negative skewness in the distribution.